# JavaScript - Function that Changes content when clicked up or down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a function that when you click up it appends to the div what you want and if you press up again will show what you want again and replace the other data, same for when you press down.

The idea is to have 5 options, the option that it starts on is decided on that users info. So say they are number 3 it will start on number 3 and if you press up it will go to number 2 if you press down it will go to number 4 and show the data with those numbers.

What I am trying to figure out is how can I make this option and then when clicked do what I want it to do.

Idea of what it looks like:
[image: Here is what it looks like:]

When you press the blue up will go up a page and only show the player that are in diamond 2. and same for the rest

```
<main>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body"></div>
            <div class="league-banner" style="height: 50px;">
                <div class="league-number" style="top: 15px; position: relative;">
                    <div class="league-rank">
                       III
                    </div>
                    <div class="league-buttons">
                        <a href="" style="top: -42px; position: relative;"><img  src="img/league/up.png"/></a>
                        <a class="sq-btn" href="" style="position: relative; top: -30px;"><img  src="img/league/down.png"/></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span style="color:#57a2dd; font-size: 20px;">DIAMOND 5 </span>  
                <span style="font-size: 20px;" class="second-banner">Diamond V</span>
                <div class="light" style="font-size:20px;">Lee Sin's Redeemers</div>
            </div>
            <div class="league-top">
                <div class="stats-header stats-row">
                    <div class="table-cell">Rank</div>
                    <div class="table-cell">Summoner</div>
                    <div class="table-cell">Emblems</div>
                    <div class="table-cell">Wins</div>
                    <div class="table-cell">Losses</div>
                    <div class="table-cell">Win Rate</div>
                    <div class="table-cell">Points</div>
                </div>
                <div class="scroll-league" id="scroll-league">
                <?php
                    if ($league_list){
                        $entrieszlist = $league_list->entries;
                        usort($entrieszlist, function($acl,$bcl){
                            return $bcl->leaguePoints-$acl->leaguePoints;
                        });

                        $index = 0;
                        foreach ($entrieszlist as $datazlistleague){

                        $playerleagueId = $datazlistleague->playerOrTeamId;
                        $playerleagueNameSummoner = $datazlistleague->playerOrTeamName;
                        $playerleagueNameSummonerDivison = $datazlistleague->division;
                        $playerleagueNameSummonerWins = $datazlistleague->wins;
                        $playerleagueNameSummonerLosses = $datazlistleague->losses;
                        $playerleagueNameSummonerLP = $datazlistleague->leaguePoints;

                        $playerleagueNameSummonerGamesPlayed = $playerleagueNameSummonerWins + $playerleagueNameSummonerLosses;
                        $playerleagueNameSummonerGamesWinRate = (100/$playerleagueNameSummonerGamesPlayed)*$playerleagueNameSummonerWins ;

                        $playerleagueNameSummonerLPtarget = $datazlistleague->miniSeries->target;
                        $playerleagueNameSummonerLPWins = $datazlistleague->miniSeries->wins;
                        $playerleagueNameSummonerLPLosses = $datazlistleague->miniSeries->losses;
                        $playerleagueNameSummonerLPProgress = $datazlistleague->miniSeries->progress;

                        if (isset($datazlistleague->miniSeries)){
                            $miniSeriesdatayesnodata = 1;
                        } else {
                            $miniSeriesdatayesnodata = 2;
                        }

                        $summonerData1;
                        if(isset($playerleagueNameSummoner)) {
                            $formatedUserName1 = str_replace(" ", "", $playerleagueNameSummoner);
                            $formatedUserName1 = mb_strtolower($formatedUserName1, 'UTF-8');
                            $sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM players_data WHERE sum_name = "' . $formatedUserName1.'"';
                            $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

                            if($result1->num_rows > 0) {
                                while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
                                    $GLOBALS['summonerData1'] = unserialize($row1['summoner_info']);
                                }
                            } else {
                                storeData($conn, $apiKey, $playerleagueNameSummoner, 'players_data');
                                header("Refresh:0; url=leaguesprofile1.php?userName=".$_GET['userName']."");
                            }
                        } else {

                        }
                        $sumiconid1 = $summonerData1->profileIconId;
                        $index++;
                        echo '<div class="stats-data stats-row loser" data-ladder_id="'.$playerleagueId.'" data-ladderdivison_id="'.$playerleagueNameSummonerDivison.'"  data-promos1or2="'.$miniSeriesdatayesnodata.'">
                            <div class="table-cell rank">'.$index.'</div>
                                <div class="table-cell change-selected">
                                    <a href="profile2.php?userName='.$playerleagueNameSummoner .'">
                                        <div style="display: table;">
                                            <div style="display: table-row;">
                                                <div class="table-cell-2">
                                                    <div class="summoner-icon" style="background-image: url(http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/profileicon/'.$sumiconid1 .'.png);"></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="table-cell-2">'.$playerleagueNameSummoner .'</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="table-cell">
                                        <div style="display: inline-block;" original-title=""> ';

                                        if($datazlistleague->isHotStreak == true){
                                           echo '<img  src="img/league/Hot_streak.png"/>';
                                        } else if($datazlistleague->isHotStreak == false){
                                           echo '<img  src="img/league/streak_none.png"/>';
                                        }
                                        echo '</div><div style="display: inline-block;" original-title="">';

                                        if($datazlistleague->isFreshBlood == true){
                                            echo '<img src="img/league/Recruit.png"/>';
                                        } else if($datazlistleague->isVeteran == true){
                                            echo '<img src="img/league/Veteran.png"/>';
                                        } else if ($datazlistleague->isFreshBlood == false && $datazlistleague->isVeteran == false){
                                             echo '<img src="img/league/Recruit_none.png"/>';
                                        }

                                        echo '</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="table-cell change-selected">'.$playerleagueNameSummonerWins.'</div>
                                    <div class="table-cell change-selected">'.$playerleagueNameSummonerLosses.'</div>
                                    <div class="table-cell change-selected">'.number_format((float)$playerleagueNameSummonerGamesWinRate, 1, '.', '').'%</div>
                                    <div class="table-cell change-selected">'; 

                                    echo $playerleagueNameSummonerLP.'LP';
                                    echo '</div>

                                </div>';
                            }
                        }
                ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

CODE - What it should do is depending if the data-attribute called "data-ladderdivison_id" is I then show when page I showen if it is V then show that data on page V but using a up and down button from 1 - 5 to change.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If using an API to show the data, design the API to accept a "top" and "limit". Limit the results to "5" and get the results starting from "3", "4", "2" etc

Comment: Create an array of your divs, or something like that, and have your two buttons increase or decrease the position of the array. If you provided some sample code it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Okay il provide my current code I have for this

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look at the structure your data is in and determine fairly early on in the script which bit is the "current important" entry point, that would probably be an indexer into an array containing your leagues.

You can do this for example by passing a parameter via the url that you then pickup in the beginning of your script, or initialize to some predefined point (probably 0 for the first league).

```
// take the ?league=... from the url or set it to 0
$currentLeagueIndex = isset($_GET['league']) ? $_GET['league'] : 0;
```

then where you're rendering the buttons you can point to the current url with that index plus or minus one.

```
$hrefPrevious = $currentLeagueIndex-1 > -1 // bounds check for sanity
              ? 'my-url?league=' . ($currentLeagueIndex-1);
              : 'javascript:void()';

$hrefNext = ($currentLeagueIndex+1) < count($allLeagues)
          ? 'my-url?league=' . ($currentLeagueIndex+1);
          : 'javascript:void()';
```

Comment: Not fully understanding how it would work as never use java script much and trying to do for school project

Comment: you're using php, not javascript though. the same applies to javascript though.

Comment: Yes, i know that but i mean to append each div to the correct page how would i do that